When is a group action "setwise" faithful?
Let $G$ be a group that acts on $X$.
When does the following holds for all nonempty $A,B\subseteq G$?

If $Ax=Bx$ for every $x\in X$, then $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$.

Clearly, the action has to be faithful.
On the other hand, regular actions have this property.
What else is known?

I don't understand the close votes. Can someone explain?

This is an interesting question. Clearly, faithful on its own is not enough. The standard action of the symmetric group $S_n$ is faithful but for $n \geq 3$ you can construct two disjoint subsets that both map each element to the full set ${1,...,n}$.

So here is an additional observation: $G$ cannot have a transitive proper subgroup because if $H$ is such a subgroup and $g \notin H$ we have $Hx=Hgx=X$ for all $x \in X$ but $H$ and $Hg$ have empty intersection.

Not sure if this helps somehow, but your condition can be rephrased as: every pairwise disjoint subsets $A,B$ of $G$ give rise to non-overlapped (setwise) "segments" of the orbits of every $x\in X$.

@Kan't I don't think it can. First of all we don't get non-overlapping just not equal and also we don't get "for all $x$" but just "for at least one $x$". Or am I misreading your characterisation?

You are absolutely right on both points, @SebastianSchoennenbeck, I "mis-contrapositivized" (as for the former, I wrote "overlapping" but I had in mind "exactly overlapping", actually).

I still don't get why people want to close this question. This is a perfectly valid interesting question.

All close votes have been removed. 3 answers have been posted, which however are all deleted now because they turned out to be incorrect.

Trivial remark:  $Ax=Bx \iff AG_x = B G_x$. So it's a condition on a group and a family of subgroups (stabilisators). Even for transitive actions it's interesting. It's not enough to consider just one stabilisator here.

@user1162811 Do you have any thoughts yourself or maybe a motivation where this problem arises. I still think it's an interesting question but so far nobody seems to have made any actual headway.

@SebastianSchoennenbeck I came up with the question while working in [model-theory]. But it is not directly connected with any problem there. Still, I thought it was interesting in itself. Even restricting the question to sets A, B, of size two, I do not understand what's happening.
